# How to change imageres.dll.mun icons using regedit?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, icons, regedit

Windows default icons are stored in `C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll` and `C:\WINDOWS\SystemResources\imageres.dll.mun`. I can change `SHELL32.dll` icons using regedit without changing the real file by changing some keys in this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons
```

[image]

I wanna do something like this for `imageres.dll.mun`.

**How can I find regedit path for it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no registry entries for `.mun` files inside
`C:\Windows\SystemResources`.
The whole point of migrating icon resource files from being embedded
in DLLs in the protected directory of `C:\Windows\System32`,
was to make them easily editable by users.

The folder `C:\Windows\SystemResources` itself is not protected and
you may change any of the contained files, using any icon editor of
your choice.
If the editor refuses to accept files with the `.mun` extension,
you may need to rename the file (it's better in all cases to copy
it elsewhere while editing).

For example, here is
[Greenfish Icon Editor](http://greenfishsoftware.org/)
editing `imageres.dll.mun`:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer Harry.. I might add that the statement `Windows default icons are stored in`.. no, *SOME* or even most default icons are stored in. I if I were you (OP), I would educate myself on the purpose of HKCR\<.ext> as in `HKCR\.txt` -> `HKCR\txtfile` and look at the subkeys.